# Outlook mail/calendar items give errors after server migration

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Last Friday our Exchange server was migrated, by our external system administrator, to a new server, with a new server name. Since then we have problems with the calendar/mail items that were created/sent/received on the old server:

- Reply to mails get bounced if we use auto complete in the To field. If we cancel auto complete and manually enter the (same) e-mail address then there's no problem. Our system administrator says this is because auto complete fills in the old server name (???).
- Calendar items created on the old server cannot be edited (without an error) and must be recreated if we want to change them.

Our system administrator says these problems are normal with a server migration. I cannot believe this. There must be a better way. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're wrong.

1. Intra-organization Outlook auto-complete entries actually reference the mailbox by GUID, rather than the email address.  New mail server, new mailbox GUIDs.  The old entries refer to GUIDs that don't exist anymore, hence the bounce.
2. For the reasons similar to the reason above, `Send-As` and existing calendaring entries often "break" with a mail migration.  Depending on the details of your setup and migration, this may be fixable or worked-around, or it may not be.  Either way, this type of issue is definitely "normal" with a mail migration.